# segmentation fault when trying to concat nodes

Tags: c

I have written the following code:

```
void concat_nodes(struct strnode *head, char *str)
{
    struct strnode *create = head;
    int n, j;
    int i = 0;
    while (create != NULL)
    {
        n = strlen(create->str);
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j, ++i)
        {
            str[i] = create->str[j];
        }
        str[i++] = ' ';
    }

    str[i] = '\0';
}
```

What this code is meant to do is modify `str` to be a string representation of the contents of a list with a given head. For example the linked list `ah--->bal--->sed` should produce the string `"ah bal sed"` with no space after `sed`. My implementation currently when ran gives me "Segmentation Fault". Any help would be much appreciated.

NOTE: In the main function I am calling it as shown below:
`concat_nodes(n3, str)`, str being an array `char str[100] = "";` and `n3` being the third node.

Structure:

```
struct strnode
{
    char str[5];
    struct strnode * next;
};
```

Comment: `strlen()` not necessary, simply `for (j = 0; create->str[j]; ++j, ++i) {...}` make sure each member `char str[5];` contains a valid *nul-terminated* string before you attempt to concatenate the strings from all nodes. And `create = create->next;` after `str[i++] = ' ';`

Comment: Make sure that str has at least  n_nodes *5+1 bytes

Comment: Try using a debugger.  Amazing tools, I'll bet you can see what's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this cycle condition:

```c
while (create != NULL)
```

... and then look at where you modify `create`... *nowhere*. The cycle will never end and will keep iterating over `str[i]` until it `i` reaches the end of `str` and overflows, causing undefined behavior, most likely resulting in a segmentation fault.